# How to filter an array in MS Access

Tags: arrays, ms-access

I am writing an array which can compare with my database(query). May I know how can I make it so it can include a "Or" logic within my array? Because I would like to get the output like Filter = myArray(0) Or myArray(1) Or myArray(2) ... Since I don't have the number of my array because it is depends on how many inputs did the user type, so I just have a myArray(x). 
Thank you.

```
Private Sub TestButton_Click()
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim Status_Input As Variant
Dim x As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim Status_Filter As Variant

Status_Input = Forms![try2].StatusInput

myArray = Split(Status_Input, ";")

For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
MsgBox " " & myArray(x) & " "             'MsgBox = 03 20 27 (3 MsgBoxes)

Status_Filter = _
"[Status] Like " & myArray(x)

Debug.Print Status_Filter
Me.Filter = Status_Filter
Me.FilterOn = True

Next x
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append filters to eachother, separating them with `OR`. Also, I recommend you use `Like` only when you need to use wildcards.

If you don't use `Like`, you can optimize the code by using `[Status] IN(1, 2, 3)` instead of `[Status] Like 1 OR [Status] Like 2 OR [Status] Like 3`.

```
Status_Filter = "[Status] Like " & myArray(LBound(myArray)) 'Note: fails if myArray is empty
For x = LBound(myArray) + 1 To UBound(myArray)
    Status_Filter = Status_Filter & " OR [Status] Like " & myArray(x)
Next x
Me.Filter = Status_Filter
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code, you could eventually try another path.

```
status_filter = "status IN ( " & replace(status_input,";",",") & ")"
```

this should evaluate to something like:

```
status_filter = "status IN (2, 4, 6)"
```

Since status_input is already a list, if the values are numeric, the above should work, and be efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. How about they are not numbers?

Comment: Because I found that I must add a ' ' for my input texts to make the filter works. e.g. 'ABCD';'EDKN';'JTS'

Comment: @BeckoChiu right, but I think you should have 'ABCD','EDKN','JTS' instead (with `,`, not `;`)